# ColdFusion UDF Syntax - Structclear Etc

Tags: coldfusion, user-defined-functions

I'd like to create a UDF that I can call that will emulate the following lines of code. The goal is to kill a user's session (various login data) while retaining their shopping cart data. The code works, but I haven't been able to get a UDF version of it to work yet. Any tips?

```
<!--- move cart to temporary variable --->
<cfset temp_cart = arrayToList(session.cart)>

<!--- kill entire session --->
<cfset foo = structclear(session)>

<!--- re-initialize cart --->
<cfset session.cart = ArrayNew(1)>

<!--- move temporary cart back to new session cart --->
<cfset session.cart = listToArray(temp_cart)>
```

Not even sure where to begin, but here's my messed up UDF so far:

```
function LogOut()
    {
  temp_cart = arrayToList(session.cart); 
  foo = structclear(session);
  session.cart = ArrayNew(1);
  session.cart = listToArray(temp_cart);
}
```

Comment: It's hard to tell where you're going wrong with your UDF without you posting the code for it, and telling us where it's going wrong...

Comment: OK, thanks for the update.  So what's it not doing what you want it to do?

Comment: The version above generates an error: "Routines cannot be declared more than once." Googling that error generates a lot of hits about closing tags with a slash, which is irrelevant here AFAIK.

Comment: Those hits are not irrelevant if you're defining your UDF in a custom tag and then invoking the custom tag with a trailing slash (makes the custom tag run 2x unless you make allowances for that in code ... can't remember the variables off the top of my head). Another option to the answer below (which you've accepted) is looping over the items in the session struct and using `structDelete()` where the key is not "cart".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just whilst we clarify what the problem is here, there's some changes you could make to that UDF to improve the code quality:

```
function LogOut(){
    var temp_cart = session.cart;
    structclear(session);
    session.cart = temp_cart;
}
```

That should blow away all your session variables except the cart.

(I've just seen your new comment about the "routines cannot be declared more than once")

OK, so the problem is not your function, it's how you're loading it in.  Where are you delcaring this function?  You are obviously declaring it in a file that is being used more than once in the same request.  Can you not put this function in your Application.cfc or Application.cfm?  Or in a UDF library that you make sure you only include once per request?

What version of CF are you on?

Comment: Okay, I still don't see how it was getting called twice, but I moved it to my normal "library" page and it seems to be working great now. Thanks so much for all your help! Oh, and this is on a CF9 server, I believe.